# Class does not conform to protocol. Why?

Tags: swift, syntax, protocols

```
class Controller<U: NSObject> {}

protocol Robert {
  associatedtype T
  associatedtype U: Controller<T>
  var fetcher: U { get }
}

class Telephone: NSObject {}

class Object: Telephone {}

class Turtle: Controller<Object> {}

class Fish: Robert {

  typealias T = Object
  typealias U = Turtle

  let x = Turtle()

  var fetcher: Turtle {
    return x
  }

}
```

I don't understand why. Any help appreciated.

When selecting the XCode 'fix it' option, a stub for 'Fetcher is inserted. But there is already a typealias for Fetcher.

Comment: Does Turtle need to be a Controller<Chapperone>?

Comment: yes turtle does need to be a Controller<Chapperone> in this hypothetical situation

Comment: Raised as bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6218

Comment: Not pretty sure, but it seems that it is a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been recognized [as a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6218) in Swift 4. For now we must avoid associated types constrained by types that have generic constraints.

So this is not cool

```
associatedtype U: Controller<T>
```

Removing it results in the following, which works.

```
protocol Robert {
  associatedtype T: NSObject
  var fetcher: Controller<T> { get }
}
```